# What's wrong with the last two layers of this U-net?

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I'm building a U-net for a two-class image segmentation problem using Keras. I'm loosely following the example given here: https://github.com/zhixuhao/unet .  Following that example, the last few layers of the decoder (including the output layer) look like:

```
    up9 = UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv8)
    merge9 = concatenate([conv1,up9], axis = 3)
    conv9 = Conv2D(16, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(merge9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(16, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(conv9)

    conv9 = Conv2D(2, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(conv9)
    conv10 = Conv2D(1, 1, activation = 'sigmoid',padding='same')(conv9)
```

The key problem that I'm finding is that when I remove this line:

```
conv9 = Conv2D(2, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(conv9)
```

then the U-net fails to train at all (using binary crossentropy), and I can't figure out why this layer is necessary given that I have seen almost identical U-nets elsewhere that skip this layer entirely.

Can anyone help shed some light here on why this layer is necessary? If I were to make a WAG, I'd say it has something to do with the fact that we want to go down to 2 filters to represent each class? Does it have something to do with the expected output shape (128x128x1) in this case?

Comment: what do you meant by "the U-net fails to train at all"

Comment: The loss runs downhill with high accuracy, but it's just predicting zeros.

Comment: The loss runs downhill? This is strange, if the loss goes down then it should predict exactly what you feed it. Your target data isn't zeros right?

Comment: Yes, it's not all zeros, but there is a severe class imbalance.